# converting raw queries to prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

suppose I have my 1995 fashion function meant to send queries to mysql.
I have lots of queries on my project and I'm looking for a function/class able to parse the raw query (suppose: SELECT foo from bar where pizza = 'hot' LIMIT 1) 
and create a prepared statement with php. do you have any tips on that?
is it worth it? or it's better to just rewrite all the queries?

I can count 424 queries on my project, and that's just SELECTs

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function prepare1995Sql_EXAMPLE ($sqlString) {

    # regex pattern
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/\'.*?\'/';

    # best to use question marks for an easy example
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = '?';

    # perform replace
    $preparedSqlString = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $sqlString);

    # grab parameter values
    $pregMatchAllReturnValueHolder = preg_match_all($patterns[0], $sqlString, $grabbedParameterValues);
    $parameterValues = $grabbedParameterValues[0];

    # prepare command:
    echo('$stmt = $pdo->prepare("' . $preparedSqlString . '");');
    echo("\n");

    # binding of parameters
    $bindValueCtr = 1;
    foreach($parameterValues as $key => $value) {
    echo('$stmt->bindParam(' . $bindValueCtr . ", " . $value . ");");
    echo("\n");
    $bindValueCtr++;
    }

    # if you want to add the execute part, simply:
    echo('$stmt->execute();');
}

# TEST!
$sqlString = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE name = 'foobar' or nickname = 'fbar'";
prepare1995Sql_EXAMPLE ($sqlString);
```

Sample output would be:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE name = ? or nickname = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, 'foobar');
$stmt->bindParam(2, 'fbar');
$stmt->execute();
```

This would probably work if all your sql statements are similar to the example, conditions being strings. However, once you require equating to integers, the pattern must be changed. This is what I can do for now.. I know it's not the best approach at all, but for a sample's sake, give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend regexp search for these queries(i think they should have pattern), later sort them and see which ones are similar/could be grouped.

Also if you have some kind of log, check which ones are executed most frequently, it doesnt make much sense to move rare queries to prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you should rewrite your queries. Using regular expressions would work, but you might find that some queries can't be handled by a pattern. The problem is there's alot of complexity in queries for just one pattern to parse'em all. Also, it would be best practice and consistent for your code to simply do the work and rewrite your queries.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enable a trace facility and capture the SQL commands as they are sent to the database.  Be forewarned, that what you are about to see will scare the pants off you:)